# rvm install 3.2.2 curl: (60) SSL certificate problem: certificate has expired

Tags: curl, rvm

Error: openssl@1.1: Failed to download resource "openssl@1.1"
Failure while executing; `/usr/bin/env /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/shims/shared/curl --disable --cookie /dev/null --globoff --show-error --user-agent Homebrew/4.1.2-33-gc531a35\ \(Macintosh\;\ Intel\ Mac\ OS\ X\ 10.14.5\)\ curl/7.54.0 --header Accept-Language:\ en --retry 3 --fail --location --silent --head https://www.openssl.org/source/openssl-1.1.1u.tar.gz` exited with 60. Here's the output:
curl: (60) SSL certificate problem: certificate has expired

help